# Broadcom Wireless Driver not working after installing Juno

Tags: release-juno

I recently installed Juno to my laptop and i found that WIFI is not working anymore. Previously, I had Loki installed, and WIFI was working fine. Because wifi is not working, I cannot installed any further update (driver, etc).

My laptop is HP Envy 15".

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: check on this link. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
Do a search on the link below

Answer (score 0):

I put my findings here, just in case anybody run into the same problem.

HP 15" Envy uses broadcom wireless driver, you can find this out by invoking the following command

```
 lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

This will get a response like this.

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Answer on for the [this askubuntu.com question](https://01:00.0%20Network%20controller%20[0280]:%20Broadcom%20Limited%20BCM43142%20802.11b/g/n%20[14e4:4365]%20(rev%2001)) explained the things that needs to be done quite extensively.

Comment: Please check the link, I think its broken.